# add missing rows in the table (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have two table. I want to add missing rows to table2 from table1. Then table2 will be sorted according to point if it's possible..
[image: table2]
[image: table1]

Comment: A "Table" in Excel has a very specific meaning.  Those are not tables. [More about tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)   I also recommend using "Center Across Selection" instead of "Merge Cells"

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished a number of ways. Simplist:

Game Column:
=Sayfa1!A3

Date Column:
=VLOOKUP(Sayfa2!A3,Sayfa1!A2:C6,2,FALSE)

Point Column:
=VLOOKUP(Sayfa2!A3,Sayfa1!A2:C6,3,FALSE)

You can then sort by an of the columns and it will not affect the first sheet.

Comment: This does not "add missing rows".  Also, VLOOKUP is extraneous, it can be replaced with Sayfa1!B3, Sayfa1!C3, etc.  Arguably, this isn't any better than copy and paste unless dynamic ranges are used - which touches on one of the benefits of using tables, the second table would expand automatically.